# Should the attribute "placeholder"'s text be printed after sending HTML to a printer?

Tags: css, html, firefox, printing, placeholder

I'm noticing a discrepancy between the outputs of printing this simple jsfiddle in Chrome and FireFox:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qrqug/

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Hello World" />
```

It seems that Google Chrome prints the 'Hello World' text, but FireFox does not.

Looking [at the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-placeholder-attribute) I don't see any descriptions of actions to take for placeholder during print.

Will this vary based on browser implementation? Or is it defined in the spec somewhere else? Any way to force FF to print the placeholder with JavaScript, CSS, or HTML?

Here's FireFox not rendering it when I print to CutePDF. I can confirm that it also doesn't render when printed to a physical printer, but you'll have to take my word for it:

[image]

Here's Google Chrome:

[image]

Comment: Just to be sure, you are talking about literally printing out a website from a printer on to paper?

Comment: Yes, I am talking about literally printing out a website from a printer onto paper, or printing to PDF. I've added a couple of examples to my original post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all I'd like to direct you to the following article:
http://laurakalbag.com/labels-in-input-fields-arent-such-a-good-idea/ only using placeholders which function as "labels" might not be such a good idea.

Of course if you want to print the placeholder in all browsers you could do something like in the good ol' days. Example:

```
<div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="test">
    <span>test</span>
<div>
```

CSS

```
div{position:relative;}
span{position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;display:none;}
```

Print CSS

```
span{display:block;}
```

Of course if you want you can auto-generate those spans with JavaScript. Get the value from the placeholders and create a `span` in de `div`

Answer (score 0):

In a fairly recent article (http://drublic.de/blog/printing-the-web/) it was tested and mentioned how a number of CSS rules performed differently in each browser when printing a site. As it would look from your testing, the same applies to some newer html attributes.

When it comes to `placeholder` I'd imagine printing it is similar to styling it in CSS, which as Chris  Coyier points out (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/), requires vendor prefixes, because each browser handles it a little differently.

However, as has been mentioned here and in numerous articles, `placeholder` text should complement an existing label and not be relied upon by themselves. So if not shown (whether it be in an unsupported browser, or a printed copy of the site), no usability or information is lost.